# Incremental sha256sum computation

Tags: c, cryptography

I ran across an interesting computation for a sha256sum that did not rely on the openssl or crypto libraries [pdfcrack/sha256.c](https://github.com/robins/pdfcrack/blob/master/sha256.c). The only difficulty with either of the functions (`sha256` and `sha256f`) was they required the total number of bytes be provided. That makes for rather large allocation when wanting a sum for large files. OpenSSL provides for a final sha256sum based on intermediate calculations using less than the entire number of bytes allowing for a small fixed buffer to be used and the sum computed by calling `SHA256_Update` on the individual buffers that make up a file, and then a final call to `SHA256_Final` to compute the final sum.

Starting with the [pdfcrack/sha256.c](https://github.com/robins/pdfcrack/blob/master/sha256.c) file, out of curiosity rather than any real need, I decided to see if that code could be split in a manner that would allow final sha256sum to be computed from incremental portions of input in a way similar to how it is handled in openssl. This code followed.

Similar to OpenSSL, a context struct is provided to hold the intermediate working values for the sum. This ended up being more of a necessity than any desire to do something similar. The reason being, limiting access to intermediate values through an opaque pointer pretty much dictated the approach. The remainder was just chasing what a sha256sum was down the rabbit-hole to figure out how the total function could be split into intermediate calculations, and then accounting for partial blocks of data from input, etc.

What I am looking for is comments on whether my use of the context struct makes sense in the way it is handled, whether there may be some way around having to dynamically allocate the context behind the scenes (I haven't come up with any, and since there is only a single allocation and free, it isn't a big performance concern). I would also like comment on the `static hdefault` used to store the final sum if for some reason the user provides a `NULL` pointer as a parameter (that tweak was borrowed directly from openssl, I originally had the functions as `void` rather than returning a pointer, but that approach made more sense) Any other general comments are welcome as well. Just note the macros and the `sha256hashblock` were pretty much straight pulls from the pdfcrack file.

The header and source file for the sha256sum implementation is provided below. A short driver file follows that mimics what `sha256sum` does from the command line. A gcc compile string would be:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast sha256d.c \
  -o sha256fread sha256fread.c
```

**sha256d.h**

```
#ifndef _SHA256_DCR_H_
#define _SHA256_DCR_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define HASHL256 32

typedef struct ctx_t ctx;

ctx *sha256_init (void);
void sha256_update (ctx *c, const uint8_t *msg, const uint64_t msglen);
uint8_t *sha256_final (ctx *c, uint8_t *hash);
void sha256_free (ctx *c);

uint8_t *sha256 (const uint8_t *msg, const uint64_t msglen, uint8_t *hash);

#endif /** _SHA256_DCR_H_ */
```

**sha256d.c**

```
#include "sha256d.h"

enum { HBLK256 = 8, DGST256 = 64 }; /* block & digest size */

struct ctx_t {  /** context for intermediate computations */
    uint8_t blk[DGST256],   /* storage for sha block */
            blklen;         /* stored block length */
    uint32_t h[HBLK256];    /* working variables */
    uint64_t msglen;        /* total message length */
};

/** sha256 computation macros */
#define ROTR(x, n) (( x >> n ) | ( x << (32 - n)))

#define Choice(x, y, z) ( z ^ ( x & ( y ^ z )))
#define Majority(x, y, z) (( x & y ) ^ ( z & ( x ^ y )))

#define Sigma0(x) (ROTR(x, 2) ^ ROTR(x, 13) ^ ROTR(x, 22))
#define Sigma1(x) (ROTR(x, 6) ^ ROTR(x, 11) ^ ROTR(x, 25))

#define sigma0(x) (ROTR(x, 7) ^ ROTR(x, 18) ^ (x >> 3))
#define sigma1(x) (ROTR(x, 17) ^ ROTR(x, 19) ^ (x >> 10))

#define ROUND(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,k,data)           \
  h += Sigma1(e) + Choice(e, f, g) + k + data;      \
  d += h;                       \
  h += Sigma0(a) + Majority(a ,b ,c);

/** sha256 sha2 algorithm providing update to 'blk' */
static void sha256hashblock (const uint8_t *blk, uint32_t *hash) {
    uint32_t W[64];
    uint32_t A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H;
    int i;

    /* 1. Prepare the message schedule */
    for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        W[i] = ((unsigned)blk[i*4    ] << 24)
            | ((unsigned)blk[i*4 + 1] << 16)
            | ((unsigned)blk[i*4 + 2] << 8)
            |  blk[i*4 + 3];
    }
    for (; i < 64; ++i) {
        W[i] = sigma1(W[i-2]) + W[i-7] + sigma0(W[i-15]) + W[i-16];
    }

    /* 2. Initialize the eight working variables */
    A = hash[0];
    B = hash[1];
    C = hash[2];
    D = hash[3];
    E = hash[4];
    F = hash[5];
    G = hash[6];
    H = hash[7];

    /* 3. Compression loop unrolled */
    ROUND(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, 0x428a2f98, W[ 0]);
    ROUND(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 0x71374491, W[ 1]);
    ROUND(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, 0xB5C0FBCF, W[ 2]);
    ROUND(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, 0xE9B5DBA5, W[ 3]);
    ROUND(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, 0x3956C25B, W[ 4]);
    ROUND(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, 0x59F111F1, W[ 5]);
    ROUND(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, 0x923F82A4, W[ 6]);
    ROUND(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, 0xAB1C5ED5, W[ 7]);
    ROUND(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, 0xD807AA98, W[ 8]);
    ROUND(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 0x12835B01, W[ 9]);
    ROUND(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, 0x243185BE, W[10]);
    ROUND(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, 0x550C7DC3, W[11]);
    ROUND(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, 0x72BE5D74, W[12]);
    ROUND(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, 0x80DEB1FE, W[13]);
    ROUND(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, 0x9BDC06A7, W[14]);
    ROUND(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, 0xC19BF174, W[15]);
    ROUND(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, 0xE49B69C1, W[16]);
    ROUND(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 0xEFBE4786, W[17]);
    ROUND(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, 0x0FC19DC6, W[18]);
    ROUND(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, 0x240CA1CC, W[19]);
    ROUND(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, 0x2DE92C6F, W[20]);
    ROUND(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, 0x4A7484AA, W[21]);
    ROUND(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, 0x5CB0A9DC, W[22]);
    ROUND(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, 0x76F988DA, W[23]);
    ROUND(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, 0x983E5152, W[24]);
    ROUND(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 0xA831C66D, W[25]);
    ROUND(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, 0xB00327C8, W[26]);
    ROUND(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, 0xBF597FC7, W[27]);
    ROUND(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, 0xC6E00BF3, W[28]);
    ROUND(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, 0xD5A79147, W[29]);
    ROUND(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, 0x06CA6351, W[30]);
    ROUND(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, 0x14292967, W[31]);
    ROUND(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, 0x27B70A85, W[32]);
    ROUND(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 0x2E1B2138, W[33]);
    ROUND(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, 0x4D2C6DFC, W[34]);
    ROUND(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, 0x53380D13, W[35]);
    ROUND(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, 0x650A7354, W[36]);
    ROUND(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, 0x766A0ABB, W[37]);
    ROUND(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, 0x81C2C92E, W[38]);
    ROUND(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, 0x92722C85, W[39]);
    ROUND(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, 0xA2BFE8A1, W[40]);
    ROUND(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 0xA81A664B, W[41]);
    ROUND(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, 0xC24B8B70, W[42]);
    ROUND(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, 0xC76C51A3, W[43]);
    ROUND(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, 0xD192E819, W[44]);
    ROUND(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, 0xD6990624, W[45]);
    ROUND(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, 0xF40E3585, W[46]);
    ROUND(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, 0x106AA070, W[47]);
    ROUND(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, 0x19A4C116, W[48]);
    ROUND(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 0x1E376C08, W[49]);
    ROUND(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, 0x2748774C, W[50]);
    ROUND(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, 0x34B0BCB5, W[51]);
    ROUND(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, 0x391C0CB3, W[52]);
    ROUND(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, 0x4ED8AA4A, W[53]);
    ROUND(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, 0x5B9CCA4F, W[54]);
    ROUND(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, 0x682E6FF3, W[55]);
    ROUND(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, 0x748F82EE, W[56]);
    ROUND(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, 0x78A5636F, W[57]);
    ROUND(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, 0x84C87814, W[58]);
    ROUND(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, 0x8CC70208, W[59]);
    ROUND(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, 0x90BEFFFA, W[60]);
    ROUND(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, 0xA4506CEB, W[61]);
    ROUND(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, 0xBEF9A3F7, W[62]);
    ROUND(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, 0xC67178F2, W[63]);

    /* 4. Compute the intermediate hash value */
    hash[0] += A;
    hash[1] += B;
    hash[2] += C;
    hash[3] += D;
    hash[4] += E;
    hash[5] += F;
    hash[6] += G;
    hash[7] += H;
}

/** sha256_init initializes the context used for
 *  intermediate hash calculations for DGST256
 *  sized blocks.
 */
ctx *sha256_init (void)
{
    ctx *c = malloc (sizeof *c);
    if (!c) {
        perror ("sha256_init() error: memory exhausted");
        return NULL;
    }

    memset (c->blk, 0, DGST256);
    c->blklen = 0;
    c->msglen = 0;

    (c->h)[0] = 0x6a09e667;
    (c->h)[1] = 0xbb67ae85;
    (c->h)[2] = 0x3c6ef372;
    (c->h)[3] = 0xa54ff53a;
    (c->h)[4] = 0x510e527f;
    (c->h)[5] = 0x9b05688c;
    (c->h)[6] = 0x1f83d9ab;
    (c->h)[7] = 0x5be0cd19;

    return c;
}

/** sha256_update updates the context 'c' with hash for 'msg'
 *  of 'msglen' size. used to allow sha2 sum calculation for
 *  large files without requiring memory allocation to hold
 *  entire file. can be called for any size msglen.
 */
void sha256_update (ctx *c, const uint8_t *msg, const uint64_t msglen)
{
    uint8_t req = DGST256 - c->blklen,
            off = DGST256 - req;
    uint64_t i;

    c->msglen += msglen;

    if (msglen < req) {  /* handle update less than full blk */
        memcpy (&(c->blk)[c->blklen], msg, msglen);
        c->blklen += msglen;
        return;
    }

    if (c->blklen) {    /* if partial block from last update */
        memcpy (&(c->blk)[c->blklen], msg, req);
        sha256hashblock (c->blk, c->h);
    }

    msg += off;     /* no need to preserve original ptr here */
    for (i = 0; i + DGST256 <= msglen; i += DGST256)
        sha256hashblock (msg + i, c->h);

    c->blklen = msglen - i;
    memcpy (c->blk, msg + i, c->blklen);
}

/** sha256_final provides final padding of context blk
 *  before computing final sha256sum. 'hash' must be of
 *  sufficient size to store the HASHL256 (32) byte sum.
 *  if hash is 'NULL', static storage in 'hdefault' is
 *  used. a pointer to the final sha256sum is returned.
 */
uint8_t *sha256_final (ctx *c, uint8_t *hash)
{
    static uint8_t hdefault[HASHL256];
    uint32_t i;

    if (hash == NULL)
        hash = hdefault;

    /* pad the message and update context blk */
    (c->blk)[(c->blklen)++] = 0x80;
    if (c->blklen > 56) {
        while (c->blklen < DGST256)
            (c->blk)[(c->blklen)++] = 0;

        sha256hashblock (c->blk, c->h);
        c->blklen = 0;
    }
    while (c->blklen < 56)
        (c->blk)[(c->blklen)++] = 0;

    (c->blk)[56] = 0;
    (c->blk)[57] = 0;
    (c->blk)[58] = 0;
    (c->blk)[59] = 0;
    (c->blk)[60] = (uint8_t)(c->msglen >> 21);
    (c->blk)[61] = (uint8_t)(c->msglen >> 13);
    (c->blk)[62] = (uint8_t)(c->msglen >> 5);
    (c->blk)[63] = (uint8_t)(c->msglen << 3);
    sha256hashblock (c->blk, c->h);

    /* fill hash from final working variable values */
    for (i = 0; i < HBLK256; ++i) {
        hash[i*4]     = (uint8_t)((c->h)[i] >> 24);
        hash[i*4 + 1] = (uint8_t)((c->h)[i] >> 16);
        hash[i*4 + 2] = (uint8_t)((c->h)[i] >> 8);
        hash[i*4 + 3] = (uint8_t)(c->h)[i];
    }

    return hash;    /* copy to hash */
}

/** sha256_free free memory allocated to context */
void sha256_free (ctx *c)
{
    if (c)
        free (c);
}

/** sha256 computes sha256sum from bytes in 'msg'.
 *  'msglen' provides the number of bytes in 'msg',
 *   and the final sha256sum is stored in 'hash' and 
 *   a pointer returned, or if 'hash' is NULL, the
 *   static array 'hdefault' is used as storage for
 *   the sha256sum. on error a sha256sum of all zeros
 *   is returned.
 */
uint8_t *sha256 (const uint8_t *msg, const uint64_t msglen, uint8_t *hash)
{
    ctx *c = NULL;
    static uint8_t hdefault[HASHL256];

    if (hash == NULL)
        hash = hdefault;

    if (!(c = sha256_init()))
        return hdefault;
    sha256_update (c, msg, msglen);
    sha256_final (c, hash);
    sha256_free (c);

    return hash;
}
```

**sha256fread.c**

A short example file that mimics `sha256sum` use from the command line. Just give it a filename or redirect `stdin` to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include "sha256d.h"

#ifndef BUFSIZ
#define BUFSIZ 8192
#endif

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    uint8_t i, hash[HASHL256] = "";
    ctx *c = sha256_init();     /* sha context initialization */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "rb") : stdin;

    if (!c)     /* validate context allocated */
        return 1;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    for (;;) {  /* read input in BUFSIZ chunks, updating hash in ctx */
        uint8_t buf[BUFSIZ] = "";
        int64_t nread = fread (buf, 1, BUFSIZ, fp);
        if (ferror (fp)) {
            perror ("read error occurred");
            return 1;
        }
        sha256_update (c, buf, nread);
        if (nread < BUFSIZ)         /* if last chunk read, exit loop */
            break;
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    sha256_final (c, hash);         /* compute final sha256sum  */
    sha256_free (c);                /* free context, ~138 bytes */

    for (i = 0; i < HASHL256; i++)      /* output sha256sum */
        printf ("%02" PRIx8, hash[i]);
    printf ("  %s\n", fp == stdin ? "-" : argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Each length (especially `msglen`) shall be declared `size_t` rather than `uint64_t`.
- There is no reason to const-qualify `msglen`.
- Computation of

  ```
  uint8_t req = DGST256 - c->blklen,
          off = DGST256 - req;
  ```

  looks strange. `DGST256 - req == DGST256 - (DGST256 - c->blklen) == c->blklen`. I recommend shorter and cleaner

  ```
  uint8_t off = c->blklen;
  ```
- I also recommend to streamline the `sha256_update` logic. As written, it is very hard to follow. Consider something along the lines of

  ```
  void sha256_update (ctx *c, const uint8_t *msg, size_t msglen)
  {
      c->msglen += msglen;

      while (msglen > 0) {
          uint8_t chunk = min(DGST256 - c->blklen, msglen);

          memcpy(&c->blk[c->blklen], msg, chunk);

          msg += chunk;
          msglen -= chunk;
          c->blklen += chunk;

          if (c->blklen < DGST256) {
              return;
          }

          sha256hashblock (c->blk, c->h);
          c->blklen = 0;
      }
  }
  ```
- To address your direct concerns, your handling of `ctx` is perfectly reasonable. On the other hand, I would prefer `sha256_final` to assume that `hash` parameter is always valid.

Comment: Thank you. I like the `sha256_update` cleanup, and had planned a revisit. The difficulty I find depends on how `min` is implemented. If implemented as a macro, subtraction gives rise to a warning of comparison between signed and unsigned types. If implemented as a function, then a type specific `min` is needed. I have settled for `uint8_t chunk = DGST256 - c->blklen;` followed by an `if (chunk > msglen) chunk = msglen;`, but am left wondering whether or how to improve branch prediction of the test? That gets rid of the `req` (required) and `off` (offset) mirror.  The `while` is cleaner.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Your implementation of `min` looks good. I don't think you should worry about branch prediction. It seems to be peanuts compared to the amount of work done by `sha256hashblock`. If you are OK with gcc specifics, `__builtin_expect(msglen > chunk, 1)` may help. Of course, profiling is necessary.

Comment: I disagree that `struct ctx_t` member `uint64_t msglen;` should be `size_t`.  That should remain `uint64_t`. OTOH in `sha256_update (ctx *c, const uint8_t *msg, const uint64_t msglen)` should use `size_t msglen`

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for is comments on whether my use of the context struct makes sense in the way it is handled, whether there may be some way around having to dynamically allocate the context behind the scene

The usual work-around it to expose `struct ctx_t` to provide space.  Yet what OP is doing is fine.

> Any other general comments are welcome as well.

Code curiously unnecessarily limits the length to 2<sup>29</sup> even though `c->msglen` is 64-bit.

Suggested alternative code to use *byte lengths* up to 2<sup>61</sup>.

```
// (c->blk)[56] = 0;
...
// (c->blk)[63] = (uint8_t)(c->msglen << 3);

uint64_t bit_len = c->msglen;
bit_len *= 8;  // 8 bits per byte
// I like doing the above in 2 lines in case `c->msglen` is narrowed.

for (index = 63; index >= 56; index--) {
  (c->blk)[index] = (uint8_t)bit_len;
  bit_len /= 256;
}
```

---

It is not clear `c->blklen` is always in the range [0...63] when `(c->blk)[(c->blklen)++] = 0x80;` is executed.  I'd expect cleaner code in `sha256_update()` that shows this.

---

`if()` not needed.

```
   // if (c)
     free (c);
```

---

Alternative code  that I find clearer

```
// ctx *c = NULL;
....
// if (!(c = sha256_init()))
//    return hdefault;

ctx *c = sha256_init();
if (c == NULL) {
    return hdefault;
}
```

---

Use `size_t` rather than `uint64_t` to prevent accessing outside array range.

```
// uint8_t *sha256 (const uint8_t *msg, const uint64_t msglen, uint8_t *hash)
uint8_t *sha256(const uint8_t *msg, size_t msglen, uint8_t *hash)
```

---

Insure at least 32-bit math.  `unsigned` may be 16 bit.

```
// W[i] = ((unsigned)blk[i*4    ] << 24)
W[i] = ((uint32_t)blk[i*4    ] << 24)
// or 
W[i] = ((uint_fast32_t)blk[i*4    ] << 24)
```

---

No need to save a few bytes.  Let `blklen` be `unsigned` rather than `uint8_t`.

---

Pedantic code would check for overflow in `sha256_update()`

```
if (msglen > (UINT64_MAX/8 - c->msglen)) Oops();
```

---

Unclear why code uses different names `sha256d.h` and `SHA256_DCR_H`.  I'd expect `SHA256D_H`

```
// file sha256d.h
#ifndef _SHA256_DCR_H_  // why CR?
```

Comment: Thanks @chux. The `sha256d` is just because I already had the `sha256` from pdfcrack in the same directory when I started monkeying with implementing the `sha256_update`. `uint64_t` -> `size_t` change was made there (and it all places where it represented a length as suggested in the first response). I like your cleanup  on indexes between `63-56`. I've been profiling a bit the suggested changes from both responses, and the only thing I've run into is the original avoids a `memcpy` by using indexing in the `for` loop which is lost when implementing the other suggested `while`. I'll keep at it.

Comment: And whether it makes a whole lot of sense or not, the objective was to avoid exposing `struct ctx_t` and only expose an opaque pointer. Personally exposing the struct doesn't give me a whole lot of heartburn, but the goal was to keep as much of the hashing behind the scene. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: A way to expose the the size requirement is to union-ize with a `unsigned char` array.  The public sees the boring `unsigned char[magic_number];` while code sees both.  More on that later.

Comment: I think I got it -- that's about a brilliant solution that I didn't think of... And your `CR?`, just initials for the name at the end of the comment.

Comment: I thought I had it... My thought was to create a union along the lines of `union foo { uint8_t bytes[sizeof (struct ctx_t)]; struct ctx_t ctx; };`, but that continues to require full exposure of `struct ctx_t` to avoid the *incomplete type* issue. Where doeth my thinking go awry?

Comment: The trick is that `uint8_t bytes[n]` where `n  >= sizeof (struct ctx_t)`.  The maximum  size of `ctx_t` can be determined without `ctx_t`.  A compiler can also `_Static_assert()` as a guarantee.  It is a step closer to the precipice, yet do-able.

Comment: Ahh.. That is the puzzle piece I missed. I was running around trying to come up with a scheme that would make `bytes` exactly `sizeof (struct ctx_t)` regardless of the compiler or padding. That ended up being a circular-firing-squad effort. A constant the maximum size that `ctx_t` could be will work fine.  So if the contents of `struct ctx_t` are 105-bytes, then I can't see any padding or alignment taking more than `23`  bytes on any compiler making `128` a safe even power of 2 maximum.